# Should this question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

I have made several edits and have completely reworded my question. It is presently closed. Should it be reopened?
Here is the link:

[Could the universe have a self-originated source?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15069/could-the-universe-have-a-self-originated-source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is much better as written. I have nominated it for reopening.

Note that when you wrote:

> When one tries to explain and understand the origins of the universe,
>   one always backs into **the 'but where did that come from' wall**.

we philosophers usually refer to this concept as an "infinite regress". A quick Google search of this term will lead you to many interesting and related ideas with regard to the universe and its causation (in case you haven't checked them out already):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_cause
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_argument

[image: Big Bang]

Comment: Thanks very much, @stoicfury, for your support.